# Is there a search engine over Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning -related sites?

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Sometimes it is necessary to dig into Artificial Intelligence or specifically Machine Learning problems to make a research. Common googling (in my own experience) usually doesn't help much due to a lot of irrelevant or paid material among the results. Google Scholar in contrast is limited to scientific publications only, sometimes it is too narrow.

I wonder if there is a kind of dedicated search engine over AI- and ML-related sites?

Comment: What kind of material besides scientific publications is interesting for you?

Comment: Well, any material that helps to understand problem. I'm not a big professional in the field and sometimes even a good blog post describing some technique and it's use-cases helps much. Software is another example... (thanks for grammar corrections in my question, English is not my native language and I have to practice it more)

Comment: Regarding blog posts and the like, you will probably have to use buzzwords from said papers in order to find blog posts and the like (by experts). Websearch is usually unbeatable if you know the correct words, so start by building vocabulary. Free online lectures are a great way to go; there are plenty to find, iirc. (Regarding English, don't worry. Many of us are non-natives. Misunderstandings happen, but that's what comments and edits are for, aren't they?)

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to find a mentioned search engine, but I was able to make it myself with a help of Google Custom Search. I made a custom search engine with *.edu, *.ac.uk, *.edu.au and so on sites and domain zones, 145 in a total at this moment. From my point of view that search engine gives much better result pages, than an ordinary search. Also, the search index is almost spam-free and paid content -free.

There is a feature, that allows one to inspect what sites are included in the index, to comment them and to vote for or against them (to purge unrelevant site from the index, for example). Also, everyone is welcome to suggest new sites using a special form on the site. In short, it has all very basic machinery needed to make such scoped search engine to be community driven.

Try it at http://neatserpent.com/

Give me your feedback, please.
Do you find it helpful and better than ordinary search engine?
Would you use it?

Please, spread the word, if you like it.